# Jquery, Toggle two elements with one click, one element should appear and the other should be hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs and a button.  I want one div to be visible on click which has a display property none, and the other div to be hidden.

And this should toggle. On the next click. The second element should be visible and the first should be hidden.

I have no knowledge of Jquery.

How do I achieve this ??

I've been trying this...

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#filter").click(function(){
             $("#sidebar").toggle(function(){
                 $("#sidebar").hide();
                 $(".right-box").show();
             }, function(){
                 $("#sidebar").show();
                 $(".right-box").hide();
             });
         });
     });
</script>
```

It doesn't work fine. The div's appear and disappear in a flash

Comment: share your html and go through the jquery api to see how you can do it

Comment: start with http://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helpful for you.

HTML :

```
 <div id='content'>Hello World</div>  
 <input type='button' id='hideshow' value='hide/show'>
```

Jquery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
     jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
});
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1/)

Comment: Not working man. Tried. I have a button and two different divs. I want to toggle these div's. On click of the button , one div has to appear(default display none property) and the other visible div should hide.

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking it.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".show").click(function(){
           $(".shown").fadeToggle('slow');
           $(".hidden").fadeToggle('slow');
    });
    });
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yomisimie/noc0fqz1/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#hide").click(function(){
          $("#a").show();
          $("#b").hide();
        });
         });
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#show").click(function(){
        $("#b").show();
        $("#a").hide();
        });
      });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

  <div id="a">If you click div 1 , it will show</div>
   <div id="b">If you click div 2, it will show </div>
    <button id="hide">div 1</button>
     <button id="show">div 2</button>

   </body>
    </html>
```

Hope this will work as you needed.